# C#, Windows Forms Panel вертикальный скроллбар

Tags: c#

В панель я отправляю label с текстом, который не влезает в панель. Если делаю `panel1.AutoScroll = true` , то автоскролл по горизонтали(как на картинке), а нужно по вертикали. Как реализовать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Думаю надо сделать ограничение ввода текста по ширине окна. Тогда при переносе текста должен появляться scroll. Как это сделать я хз.

Comment: Попробуйте [это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34755681/6468198)

Comment: Обычный `TextBox` в режиме `MultyLine` умеет все это "из коробки", см. свойство `WordWrap`. И да, можно запретить его редактировать и вообще стилизовать под `Label` простой заменой стандартного цвета фона и стиля рамки  если это очень нужно. `Label` тоже умеет переносить слова, но ему нужно явно указать размер, но при этом он не умеет `AutoScroll`. Решать конечно вам, но лично я использую стилизованные `TextBox`-ы, когда нужно отображать многострочный текст со сролом, проще и быстрее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно ограничить максимальную ширину `Label` с помощью его свойства `MaximumSize`, чтобы она не превышала ширину панели (минус ширина полосы прокрутки, которая потом появится). Максимальную высоту при этом оставить без ограничений (что обозначается значением равным `0`). Тогда `Label` будет увеличиваться только по высоте, а значит будет появляться только вертикальная прокрутка.